# YUI Get class name by id

Tags: javascript, dom, yui

Is there a syntax for getting the class name by id. The class name is dynamic so I can't use

```
if(Dom.hasClass('id-name-here', 'class-name-here')
{
  Dom.removeClass('id-name-here', 'class-name-here');
  Dom.addClass('id-name-here', 'class-name-here');
}
```

I can get the src attribute using the id by doing this,

```
Dom.get('id-name-here').src
```

But when I try to adapt it to class, it is undefined

```
Dom.get('id-name-here').class
```

I am only certain of the id. Can you point me to the right documentation or teach me how...Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, it is `className` rather than `class`:

```
Dom.get('id-name-here').className;
```